# logical operation over all pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

given the following dataframe,

```
      col1       col2        col3
0      True      True        False
1      True      True         True
2     False      True         True
3     False      True         True
4     False      True         True
5     False      True         True
6      True      True         True
```

I would like a new dataframe resulting in the calculation *without* considering the number of columns to AND:

```
df.col1 & df.col2 & df.col3 & etc...
```

In other terms, how to dynamically AND pandas dataframe columns?

Please assume all values are already boolean.

Answer (score 2):

Let us try `all` =& and `any`=|

```
df.all(axis=1)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it over just 2 out of the 3 columns with pandas without using a lambda apply approach

Comment: df[df.astype(int).sum(axis=1)==2]